# How to set etag and cache-control from gulp for minified JS and CSS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, caching, gulp

I am working on an angular app, which we are serving using gulp. The problem is every time it refreshes, it takes 3-4 seconds to load(checking on Chrome). As all minified JS and CSS files are few MBs and they are downloaded each time.

I think if we cache them in browser, it should reduce the reload time significantly. Is it possible to set-Age and etag from gulp, or This is not related to gulp at all. Please let me know how this type of caching is done?

Comment: If you have chrome console open to view the timing... do you have the "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" flagged checked in the settings?

Comment: No, It is not enabled.

Comment: Gulp's webserver plugins are designed for development use. I can't see any cache control stuff in their documentation. You should probably use a more performant web server for production.

Comment: @Quentin: Any suggestions, nginx, passenger?